# Does a table that stores a subset of primary keys from another table increase the efficiency of selective SELECT queries?

Tags: database, performance, indexing

I'm interested in finding the find the most efficient way to select records from a table based on a boolean attribute.

My scenario is I have a table that holds comments made by users, I want to select all the comments that are flagged as inappropriate.

The two ideas I had to implement this are:

1. The most logical one, have a boolean attribute 'isFlagged' in the comments table

   The table would have a primary index

   I would execute:

   ```
   SELECT description FROM Comment 
   WHERE isFlagged = 1;
   ```
2. Have a table that holds the primary keys of records from the Comment table that have been flagged

   Both tables would have a primary index

   I would execute:

   ```
   SELECT description FROM Comment 
   WHERE commentID IN (SELECT FK_commentID FROM FlaggedComment)
   ```

Which would execute the most efficiently?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for the first one if and only if you have an index on the `isFlagged` field:

```
alter table comment add index idxFlagged (isFlagged)
```

Additionally, take into account that your second query is just a join (there is no need of a subquery):

```
select description from Comment c
join FlaggedComment fc on c.commentId = fc.fkCommentId
```

I bet it should take longer to execute than traversing the index on the `isFlagged` field. Anyway, I would suggest you to benchmark those two solutions and report back the results :)

Comment: The amount of time longer it will take, if any, is likely *inconsequential* more for correct indices as it will be a simple hash-match (or as the query planner decides). RDBMS' are designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: Personally, I would have it as a column in the comments table as "it's an attribute of a comment" as it is written now. However, a more complicated flagging system and...

Comment: Odds are good that PostgreSQL won't use any kind of index on a Boolean column.  You can test it with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <query>`.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is your concern, I would recommend you test both scenarios, with representative amounts of (test) data.

For what it's worth - most database systems don't benefit from indices on fields with low cardinality - especially [booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844991/indexing-boolean-fields). For a huge table, option 1 would require a table scan, which could be slow.

Option 2 *should* be faster, because you can index the commentID field - but only for the query you mention. Trying to find details about an individual comment would require a join, which might be slower.

In practice, unless you're working at extremes, it's unlikely that you'd have a measurable performance impact. That's why you should build a test rig, and try it out - the theoretical differences may have no real-world impact.